# Allow changes for Gridview webpart in sharepoint 2010 through web.config file

Tags: sharepoint

We have gridview control deployed as a web part on our SharePoint site. We are looking to limit the rows on gridview to 5. But, we do not want to mention this on our code , however we want it to be mentioned in the web.config file. So that, whenever, we decide to change the number of rows it is easy to change directly in the web.config file.

Is this possible, please let me know as it is very urgent.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Show us the code you are using that isn't working

Comment: Currently, I am checking if (dt.Rows.Count<=5){Add new row(); else lbl.Message("Only 5 uploads are allowed"); ...which I dont want to do ...I want it to be parameterized through web.config file...is this possible...I have'nt anytime modified web.config file for coding web parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't "sharepoint" but rather a general .net how do I read from my web.config file.

Welcome to the wonderful world of the configurationmanager class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx